# I need help dealing with converting Audio Files to MP4 with python

Tags: python, file, automation, type-conversion, converters

So, I am a beginner in Pyhton and recently I have covered what would be the basics of the language.

And now I have this little project in mind which is basically to create a script that can convert files in a massive way. Specifically convert .ogg files into .mp4 or .mkv files. The intention of this is to convert whatsapp audio files that come in .ogg format to make them more manipulable.

I would like hints suggestions and guidance on how I could do this. Which lib could I use to help me and where can I learn more about this and file conversion using python

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a python user, but will try to give you some direction.

There is a software called `ffmpeg`. It can be used as a command line tool to convert any audio/video files to almost any format. If you decide to use it manually then you need to download binaries [here](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases), put your .ogg file in the `/bin` directory next to `ffmpeg.exe` file and execute (here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwHU8.png) for better understanding):

```
./ffmpeg.exe -i input.ogg output.mp4
or:
./ffmpeg.exe -i input.ogg -c copy output.mp4
```

These are only basic commands, for more examples check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075992/using-ffmpeg-convert-a-file-from-one-format-to-another) answer.

**But I would suggest** to simply use a python wrapper of this tool that is already implemented, check this [quick start guide](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) with lots of examples in python. For more details [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382868/how-can-i-convert-an-ffmpeg-command-line-to-ffmpeg-python-code) answer can be also helpful.

Comment: @murilo-msa let me know if you're struggling, I'll help